# In Oracle, how do I select (and assign) rows of data that occur on the same date?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, case

When I was trying to create a unique index on our final dataset, I noticed we had data that had multiple rows for the same information. I have the following data. For the ones that have samstrat of 'IN', I need to classify the first one as 'Regular', the second as 'Duplicate' and the third one as 'Other'. The other samstrats have been classified correctly. These classifications go into a new column called sam_type.

```
ROWNUM Site_id_program   smp_date   samstrat
13      1E1-134          4/21/1983  IN
14      1E1-134          4/21/1983  IN
15      1E1-134          4/21/1983  EPI
16      1E1-134          4/21/1983  IN
17      1E1-134          4/21/1983  HYP
```

I have tried the following, but get errors related to missing parenthesis. But I'm not even sure if you can use such a long line of code in the CASE function or if that's even the most practical. We don't have any other identifying information for these samples, so I was thinking I want to select the MIN of the ROWNUM for Regular, Second as Duplicate, and MAX as Other. But I'm not sure this is possible since ROWNUM seems to be calculated at every select statement?

```
SELECT *, 
    DECODE(samstrat,'HYP','HYPO', samstrat) AS samstrat_02,
    CASE WHEN only_once='Y' THEN 'Annual'
        WHEN samstrat = 'HYP' THEN 'Other'
        WHEN samfreq = 'A' AND type = 'REG' THEN 'Annual'
        WHEN samfreq = 'A' AND type = 'DUP' THEN 'Duplicate'
        WHEN sample_no = 2 THEN 'Duplicate'
        --WHEN (MIN(ROWNUM(site_id_program ||'x'|| samstrat ||'x'|| smp_date ))) THEN 'Regular'
        --WHEN (Middle/SecondROWNUM(site_id_program ||'x'|| samstrat ||'x'|| smp_date ))) THEN 'Duplicate'
        --WHEN (MAX(ROWNUM(site_id_program ||'x'|| samstrat ||'x'|| smp_date ))) THEN 'Other'
        ELSE 'Regular'
        END AS sam_type
    FROM waterstage.wq_meltm_1982_2010_mv_test)
```

I'd like the 3 samples in question to be properly classified as Regular, Duplicate, or Other. Ideally I would like to not have to create another materialized view for this step.

```
ROWNUM Site_id_program   smp_date   samstrat  sam_type
13      1E1-134          4/21/1983  IN        Regular
14      1E1-134          4/21/1983  IN        Duplicate
15      1E1-134          4/21/1983  EPI       Regular
16      1E1-134          4/21/1983  IN        Other
17      1E1-134          4/21/1983  HYP       Other
```

Comment: Your missing parentheses error looks like it's coming from your middle commented out line. You have two open and three close there. Additionally, you shouldn't have any problems at all with a case statement of that length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that ranking over site_id_program, smp_date, samstrat gives us what we need to then do a join with the original table. In our CASE statement, we now use site_repeat_rank to order and subsequently classify the rows of data.

```
CREATE materialized view wq_meltm_1982_2010_mv
AS
WITH with_sam_type AS (SELECT b.site_id_program, smp_date, samstrat, site_repeat_rank, 
       DECODE(samstrat,'HYP','HYPO', samstrat) AS samstrat_02, 
       CASE WHEN samstrat = 'S' THEN 'Blank'
            WHEN site_repeat_rank=1 AND samfreq = 'A' AND type = 'REG' THEN 'Annual'
            WHEN site_repeat_rank=1 AND only_once='Y' THEN 'Annual' 
            WHEN site_repeat_rank=1 AND samstrat = 'HYP' THEN 'Other'            
            --WHEN sample_no = 2 THEN '2ndSample' --sample_no=2 are pushed to bottom of site_repeat_rank BUT if the only record is sample_no=2 it is considered regular
            WHEN site_repeat_rank=1 THEN 'Regular' 
            WHEN site_repeat_rank=2 THEN '2ndSample'
            WHEN site_repeat_rank=3 THEN '3rdSample'
            WHEN site_repeat_rank=4 THEN '4thSample'
            WHEN site_repeat_rank=5 THEN '5thSample'
       END AS sam_type, 
       rowid_real
FROM
((SELECT a.*, rowid AS rowid_real,
       RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY site_id_program, smp_date, samstrat ORDER BY type DESC NULLS FIRST, sample_no ASC, rowid) AS site_repeat_rank
FROM waterstage.wq_meltm_1982_2010_mv_test a) b
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT site_id_program, 'Y' AS only_once
 FROM waterstage.wq_meltm_1982_2010_mv_test
 GROUP BY site_id_program
 HAVING COUNT(site_id_program) = 1) c
ON b.site_id_program=c.site_id_program))

SELECT a.*, samstrat_02, sam_type
FROM waterstage.wq_meltm_1982_2010_mv_test a LEFT JOIN with_sam_type b
ON a.rowid=b.rowid_real;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why does `ROWNUM = 17`, `HYP`, have `sam_type = Other`? Shouldn't it be `Regular`?

Here's one option: using analytical function `ROW_NUMBER`, using partition on `site_id_program`, `smp_date` and `samstrat`, decide which `sam_type` to use. Depending on real data you have, that might change, but - that's the general idea.

```
SQL> with test (c_rownum, site_id_program, smp_date, samstrat) as
  2    (select 13, '1E1-134', '4/21/1983', 'IN'  from dual union all
  3     select 14, '1E1-134', '4/21/1983', 'IN'  from dual union all
  4     select 15, '1E1-134', '4/21/1983', 'EPI' from dual union all
  5     select 16, '1E1-134', '4/21/1983', 'IN'  from dual union all
  6     select 17, '1E1-134', '4/21/1983', 'HYP' from dual
  7    ),
  8  inter as
  9    (select c_rownum, site_id_program, smp_date, samstrat,
 10       row_number() over (partition by site_id_program, smp_date, samstrat
 11                          order by c_rownum) rn
 12     from test
 13    )
 14  select c_rownum, site_id_program, smp_date, samstrat, rn,
 15    case when rn = 1 then 'Regular'
 16         when rn = 2 then 'Duplicate'
 17         when rn = 3 then 'Other'
 18    end sam_type
 19  from inter
 20  order by c_rownum;

  C_ROWNUM SITE_ID SMP_DATE  SAM         RN SAM_TYPE
---------- ------- --------- --- ---------- ---------
        13 1E1-134 4/21/1983 IN           1 Regular
        14 1E1-134 4/21/1983 IN           2 Duplicate
        15 1E1-134 4/21/1983 EPI          1 Regular
        16 1E1-134 4/21/1983 IN           3 Other
        17 1E1-134 4/21/1983 HYP          1 Regular

SQL>
```

Comment: Sites with HYP as the samstrat are purposefully classified as Other. EPI sites are the ones we truly want for that specific day as the Regular sample. Ideally, all IN sites would be classified as Duplicates, but that wouldn't work in the unique index. There's a chance I may end up just excluding the IN sites altogether from our final dataset since we have our Regular sample for that day, but I at least wanted to try to get them included.

Comment: This might be an option if I decide to keep the data. I was hoping I could keep all the other CASE statements so that the classifying would be consistent across all datasets (we have about 40 of them).

Comment: OK. If the general idea (analytic function which lets you decide which is which) helps, fine. Hopefully, someone else will provide yet another option.